# How to hold the records of one table in another temporary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario, like: one `ErrorLog` table is there, if there are any rows in this table for current date (`GETDATE()`) I want to hold these rows in another temporary table and need to delete the current rows in this table after exection of a stored procedure. I would like to know about the logic to implement this?

Comment: What database do you use? What solutions have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned GETDATE() function , I am assuming database is SQL Server.

```
Select * Into #currentErrorLogTable
from ErrorLogTable
where convert(varchar(11),createdDate,101)=convert(varchar(11),getdate(),101)

Delete From ErrorLogTable
Where convert(varchar(11),createdDate,101)=convert(varchar(11),getdate(),101)

Select * from #currentErrorLogTable

drop table #currentErrorLogTable
```